# How to use regex to detect missing delimitors in string?

Tags: regex

I've got a multi-line string with a specific pattern (namely '##') that may appear either at the beginning or at the end of the line. However this pattern is sometimes missing and I would like to efficiently detect where it is present and where it is missing.

I've written a solution by analyzing each line by hand, but I guess that regular expressions would offer a more efficient and stable solution. The idea would be to split the line into three groups, one for the inital delimitor, one for the data and one for the final delimitor. So having empty groups would mean missing delimitor or missing data. Here are some examples of what I mean:

```
abcd         --> ("", "abcd", "")
##abcd       --> ("##", "abcd", "")
abcd##       --> ("", "abcd", "##")
##abcd##     --> ("##", "abcd", "##")
##ab#cd##    --> ("##", "ab#cd", "##")
####         --> ("##",  "", "##")
```

I have tried this regex:

```
(##)?(.*)(\1)?
```

but the central group (.*) merges into the trailing delimitor

Using this one:

```
(##)?([^#]*)(\1)?
```

is better, but it fails for the last two examples above. Any hint ?

Comment: There are many flavors of regular expressions. if I understand correctly you want something like  (#{2})? to specify "two # symbols or nothing."

Comment: why not counting the amount of # symbols? if # not 4 times in this pattern = match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy by default. This means that `(##)?(.*)(##)?` applied to `##abcd##` will take `abcd##` to the second group, while the 3rd group will be empty (empty string matches `(##)?`).

That's why you should use non-greedy guantifier `(.*?)` for the second group.

Regex that works for all your cases is:

```
^(##)?(.*?)(##)?$
```

[**Regex Fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/1Kt1gr/2)

Comment: How about a string like `##abcd##abcd##`? (oh you just added it)

Comment: If you used `$` at the end, `(.*?)` is not necessary anymore. `(.*)` will do the work too.

Comment: @Philip Tzou, you mistake regarding non-greedy quantifier, try removing it and check the results.

Comment: @CodeFuller: I tested the non-greedy version before asking my question, but I forgot to surround by ^...$ so it didn't work for the last line. Thank's a lot for your solution !

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning and ending of a string.

How about this:

```
^(##)?(.*?)(\1)?$
```

Or (if the string contains trailing line break(s)):

```
^(##)?(.*?)(\1)?\s*$
```

I don't know what flavor of regular expression and what programming language you used. In Python, you need to enable the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) mode too. In JavaScript, you need to enable the [`m` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline) too. Other languages may have similar mechanism to specify multiline mode.

Answer (score 0):

String split using a regex and a capture group will give you what you need. This splits the string, and returns the delimiter in the results. If "##" doesn't show up at all, that means that it was not present.

```js
var strs = ["abcd",         //--> ("", "abcd", "")
"##abcd",       //--> ("##", "abcd", "")
"abcd##",       //--> ("", "abcd", "##")
"##abcd##",     //--> ("##", "abcd", "##")
"##ab#cd##",    //--> ("##", "ab#cd", "##")
"####"]         //--> ("##",  "", "##")

function splitStr(str){
  return str.split(/(##)/g)
}

strs.forEach(str => console.log(splitStr(str)))
```